# Django apply styling to update filefield

Tags: css, django, forms, filefield

I currently use django-imagekit to upload a file to a PostModel. I use the CreateView and a PostCreateForm to get the required field in the form and use css to style the form.

Now when I create the PostUpdateView, the filefield receives additional tags and text without html elements.

## post_form_update.html

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate>
{% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<div class="field-wrapper col s12 no-marg">
  <button class="btn green" type="submit" value="Submit">Voeg toe</button>
</div>

</form>
```

## generated by browser

```
<p>
  <label for="id_image">Image:</label> 
  Huidige: 
  <a href="/media/2018/10/25/20130513122019resized11651368441737.jpg">2018/10/25/20130513122019resized11651368441737.jpg</a>
  <input type="checkbox" name="image-clear" id="image-clear_id">
  <label for="image-clear_id">Wissen</label><br>
  Wijzigen:
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" id="id_image">
</p>
```

The paragraph containing the file-field shows the text "Huidige" and "Wijzigen", I would like to hide these but since they're not wrapped in an element I can't use CSS to hide them.

I can't use display:none or color: #fff since I need the input file and label tag inside the paragraph.

Any ideas?